# Is activity in Google's "Ask Question" box good for my website's SEO?

Tags: seo

For some keywords, Google shows an `Ask Questions` box. And I have seen that some websites have a long list of questions being asked and answered.

Does it have a noticeable value for SEO ranking?

**Update**:

A sample image from the `Ask Question` button.
[image]